# Apache process doesn't die after disconnection with RabbitMQ

Tags: php, apache, docker, rabbitmq, amqp

I was trying to use [Server Side Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) mechanics in my project. (This is like Long Polling on steroids)

Example from "[Sending events from the server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)" subtitle works beautifully. After few seconds, from disconnection, the apache process is killed. This method works fine.

BUT! If I try to use [RabbitMQ](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib), Apache does't get the process killed after browser disconnects from server (`es.close()`). And process leaves as is and gets killed only after the docker container restarts.

[connection_aborted](http://php.net/function.connection-aborted) and [connection_status](http://php.net/function.connection-status) don't work at all. `connection_aborted` returns only `0` and connection_status returns `CONNECTION_NORMAL` even after disconnect. It happens only when I use RabbitMQ. Without RMQ this functions works well.

`ignore_user_abort(false)` doesn't work either.

Code example:

```
<?php
use PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel;
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPTimeoutException;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

class RequestsRabbit
{
    protected $rabbit;

    /** @var AMQPChannel */
    protected $channel;

    public $exchange = 'requests.events';

    public function __construct(AbstractConnection $rabbit)
    {
        $this->rabbit = $rabbit;
    }

    public function getChannel()
    {
        if ($this->channel === null) {
            $channel = $this->rabbit->channel();

            $channel->exchange_declare($this->exchange, 'fanout', false, false, false);

            $this->channel = $channel;
        }

        return $this->channel;
    }

    public function send($message)
    {
        $channel = $this->getChannel();

        $message = json_encode($message);

        $channel->basic_publish(new AMQPMessage($message), $this->exchange);
    }

    public function subscribe(callable $callable)
    {
        $channel = $this->getChannel();

        list($queue_name) = $channel->queue_declare('', false, false, true, false);

        $channel->queue_bind($queue_name, $this->exchange);

        $callback = function (AMQPMessage $msg) use ($callable) {
            call_user_func($callable, json_decode($msg->body));
        };

        $channel->basic_consume($queue_name, '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

        while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
            if (connection_aborted()) {
                break;
            }

            try {
                $channel->wait(null, true, 5);
            } catch (AMQPTimeoutException $exception) {
            }
        }

        $channel->close();
        $this->rabbit->close();
    }
}
```

What happens:

- Browser establishes SSE connection to the server. `var es = new EventSource(url);`
- Apache2 spawns new process to handle this request.
- PHP generates a new Queue and connects to it.
- Browser closes connection  `es.close()`
- Apache2 doesn't kill process and it stays as is. Queue of RabbitMQ will not be deleted. If I do some reconnections, it spawns a bunch of processes and a bunch of queues (1 reconnection = 1 process = 1 queue).
- I close all tabs -- processes alive. I close browser -- the same situation.

Looks line some kind of PHP bug. Or of Apach2?

What I use:

- Last Docker and docker-compose
- [php:7.1.12-apache or php:5.6-apache](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) image (this happens on both versions of PHP)

Some screenshots:

[image: RabbitMQ queues]

[image: Processes]

Please, help me to figure out what's going on...

P.S. Sorry for my English. If you can find a mistake or typo, point to it in the comments. I'll be very grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you're using `send()` or `subscribe()` (or both) during your server-side events.  Assuming you're using `subscribe()` there is no bug. This loop:

```
while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
    if (connection_aborted()) {
        break;
    }

    try {
        $channel->wait(null, true, 5);
    } catch (AMQPTimeoutException $exception) {
    }
}
```

Will run until the process is killed or the connection is remotely closed from RabbitMQ.  This is normal when listening for queued messages.  If you need to stop the loop at some point you can set a variable to check in the loop or throw an exception when the SSE is ended (although I find this awkward).

Comment: No. Process will not be killed by apache2. This is the oldest bug since 2004 year -- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30301. `connection_aborted` and `connection_status` functions are not working. And these no way to fix it. It's better to use Websocketd (with the D at the end) for me